# attempt to index local

Tags: lua, love2d

I get the error:

```
libs/timer.lua:144: attempt to index local 'subject' (a nil value)

Traceback

libs/timer.lua:144: in function 'tween_collect_payload' libs/timer.lua:158: in function 'tween' classes/Button.lua:64: in function 'listenKey' states/menu.lua:35: in function 'keypressed' main.lua:58: in function <main.lua:57> [C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

I think there's problem, but i don't know where exactly:

classes/Button.lua

```
function Button:listenKey(key)
  local action = self.buttons[self.currentPosition][2]
  local prev = self.currentPosition - 1
  local nex = self.currentPosition + 1
  moveRight = function(buttonPos)
    timer.tween(.5, buttonPos, {[3] = 150}, "in-out-linear")
  end
  if key == "w" or key == "up" then
    sounds.menu.move:stop()
    sounds.menu.move:play()
    if self.currentPosition > 1 then
      -- here goes error  
      timer.tween(.5, self.buttons[nex], {[3] = 150}, "in-out-linear")
    end
    moveRight(self.buttons[self.currentPosition])
    self.currentPosition = math.max(1, self.currentPosition - 1)
  elseif key == "s" or key == "down" then
    sounds.menu.move:stop()
    sounds.menu.move:play()
    if self.currentPosition <= lume.count(self.buttons) then
      -- and here goes error 
      timer.tween(.5, self.buttons[prev], {[3] = 150}, "in-out-linear")
    end
    moveRight(self.buttons[self.currentPosition])
    self.currentPosition = math.min(lume.count(self.buttons), self.currentPosition + 1)
  elseif key == "return" then
    sounds.menu.move:stop()
    sounds.menu.enter:stop()
    sounds.menu.enter:play()
    action()
  end
end
```

Using hump.timer, middleclass libs.
Tried a lot of variations of getting next and previous positions, but anyway I can't get the right "lua-way"

Comment: Where can I read the documentation on `timer.tween()`?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff [Here](https://hump.readthedocs.io/en/latest/timer.html)

Comment: Probably `self.buttons[prev]` is `nil`.  It may happen, for example, when `prev == 0`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff it can't be `nil`. I'm checking that in `self.currentPosition > 1` and `self.currentPosition <= lume.count(self.buttons)`. So `local prev = self.currentPosition - 1` and `local nex = self.currentPosition + 1` de facto not a `nil` values, even if they are, they won't be called inside this statement.

Comment: Check it: print the value `self.buttons[prev]` before invocation of `timer.tween`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff oh gosh, you're right! I shoulda check if current position more than 1; can't run the code right now, but I see it from here. Thank you for your time and help!